# this.map.getBounds() is undefined

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I am following the Josh morony's tutorial and

trying to get the bounds information of google map.

But the outcome of getBounds() is "undefined"

How can I get the value of getBounds()?

My developing environment is

"Ionic2 (2.0.0-rc.4) + typescript"

And my code is like below

```
  initMap(): Promise<any> {

    this.mapInitialised = true;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.481223, 126.952701);

      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement, mapOptions);

      let bounds = this.map.getBounds();

      console.log(bounds); <-- output "undefined"

      resolve(true);


    });

  }
```

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: this.mapElement is ElementRef?

Comment: Also better to add the link of  the tutorial you are refering to

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :)

```
                this.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(), 
                this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), 
                this.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng(), 
                this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your map is initialized and tiles loaded by listening for the tilesloaded event.  This code example would output Latitude and Longitude values for and map bounds change such as panning or zooming.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'tilesloaded', () => { 
     console.log(this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat());
     console.log(this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng());
     console.log(this.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat());
     console.log(this.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng());
});
```